# Why does the nrf8001 bluetooth chip quit working when sd card is added to SPI bus?

Tags: arduino, sd-card, spi

I'm working on an arduino project in which I'm using an nrf8001 bluetooth breakout board and an SD card breakout board. Both chips use SPI so I should be able to just link them to the same bus. They both work fine on their own but as soon as I connect the MISO pins to both chips the bluetooth is unable to start advertising or communicate to the arduino at all.

I'm really not sure where to even start here. I tried setting both SS pins to output from the arduino code just to be sure but that didn't change anything.

Here's what I'm using to test it

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include "Adafruit_BLE_UART.h"

#define ADAFRUITBLE_REQ 10
#define ADAFRUITBLE_RDY 2
#define ADAFRUITBLE_RST 9

Adafruit_BLE_UART uart = Adafruit_BLE_UART(ADAFRUITBLE_REQ, ADAFRUITBLE_RDY, ADAFRUITBLE_RST);

void aciCallback(aci_evt_opcode_t event)
{
  switch(event)
  {
    case ACI_EVT_DEVICE_STARTED:
      Serial.println(F("Advertising started"));
      break;
    case ACI_EVT_CONNECTED:
      Serial.println(F("Connected!"));
      break;
    case ACI_EVT_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.println(F("Disconnected or advertising timed out"));
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

void rxCallback(uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t len)
{
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
   Serial.print((char)buffer[i]);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  uart.setRXcallback(rxCallback);
  uart.setACIcallback(aciCallback);
  uart.begin();
}

void loop() {
  uart.pollACI();
}
```

And here's the setup on the breadboard

[Breadboard wiring setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVWvr.jpg)

The serial monitor output is

```
Initializing SD card...initialization done.
```

But if the bluetooth was working correctly it would be

```
Initializing SD card...initialization done.
Advertising started
```

Comment: Are any of the pins or peripherals shared?

Comment: @domen the MISO, MOSI, and SCK pins are shared but they both have their own chip select pins

Comment: Have you got a scope or a logic probe (or at least voltmeter, maybe even LED) to confirm both `CS` work as expected. You can also just try only pull-up on otherwise disconnected CS and see if BT/SD interferes with the other then.

Comment: Yeah the CS pins seem to work fine. Even when I have CS on the sd card always pulled high the bluetooth chip doesn't work

Comment: It seems SPI bus sharing is tricky with SD card (basically it's not completely inactive when CS is high). See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68551/does-an-sd-card-in-spi-mode-respect-chip-select-slave-select-seems-to-be-resett and linked article, if it helps.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's my problem. I've been trying to get it working by sending an extra byte but nothing seems to work. Even when I send some random byte to no chip selected then initialize the bluetooth before the SD card it doesn't work. I don't have access to an oscilloscope so it's hard to really see what's going on so maybe I'll have to find one I can use. Is there anything that comes to mind that might be causing this issue in the meantime?